# How to enable PUT and DELETE method on nginx?

Tags: nginx, server

I have this website which i reverse proxied using nginx,
My website has CRUD operations so it uses HTTP PUT and DELETE methods to update and delete records!

I found out that using --http_dav_module solves the issue,
so i added following code into my nginx.conf file,

```
server {
     server_name  autoattendance.ml www.autoattendance.ml;

     location  / {
          dav_methods PUT DELETE;

          proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
```

but it did not solve the issue,
these request are working fine on my local machine but not on the server!

The console error that i am getting is:

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYUBj.jpg)
// ps : sorry, i'm not allowed to include images at this point it seems,

The complete nginx.conf file is:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        server_name  autoattendance.ml www.autoattendance.ml;

        location  / {
        dav_methods PUT DELETE;

            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

    
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/autoattendance.ml/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/autoattendance.ml/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }



    server {
    if ($host = www.autoattendance.ml) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = autoattendance.ml) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  autoattendance.ml www.autoattendance.ml;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}}
```